# Find the number of other values of n for which $S_{n}$ = r is

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

Consider an arithmetic progression whose first term is $4$ and
the common difference is $-0.1.$ Let $S_{n}$ stand for the sum of the first
n terms. Suppose r is a number such that $S_{n}$ = r for some n. Then
the number of other values of n for which $S_{n}$ = r is

I am getting $S_{n}$ as $$\frac{n}{2}(8.1-0.1*n)$$
Next how to process further?

Comment: Equate the expression for $S_n$ to $r$ and solve the quadratic equation.

Comment: @DevanshKamra What are you talking about? Did you try your own idea? It is not really a trivial problem.

Comment: @peter.petrov What's the problem? He needed other values of $n$ where $S_n$ is equal to $r$, he has the expression for $S_n$, equating it to $r$ would give a quadratic equation in the form of $n$ solving which would give the values of $n$ where $S_n=r$. I don't see what you find troubling here.

Comment: @DevanshKamra OK, solve it yourself first and you will see what is troubling here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's rewrite your expression as $$S_n=\frac{81n-n^2}{20}$$  Now if the sum of the first $m$ terms equals the sum of the first $n$ terms, we have $$\frac{81n-n^2}{20}=\frac{81m-m^2}{20}$$
Can you finish it now?

**EDIT**

We have $n+m=81$ or $m=81-n$.  But $m$ must be a positive integer for this to make sense.  So there is $1$ solution if $1\leq n\leq80$ and no solution if $n\geq81$.

**P.S.**

To be absolutely complete, I should note that the case $m=n$ is not possible.

Comment: can u say why are u writing this "if the sum of the first m terms equals the sum of the first n terms"

Comment: I get $n=\dfrac{8.1\pm \sqrt{72.9-0.8r}}{0.2}$. What's wrong in this?

Comment: @DevanshKamra The problem is that it involves an unknown value $r$.  You should be able to answer the question instantly, just knowing the value of $n$.

Comment: @DevanshKamra how can u conclude ans from this?

Comment: @Silverstalon That's the question, isn't it?  $S_n$ is the sum of the first $n$ terms, and we're asked how many values of $m$ are there such that $S_n=S_m$

Comment: @saulspatz So are you saying that the value of $n$ won't depend on $r$?

Comment: @DevanshKamra No, I'm saying that you shouldn't have to solve a quadratic.  Please read my answer.

Comment: @saulspatz my bad! I have not gone through your solution deeply! .Thanks. after getting m+n =81 ...how to conclude ?

Comment: @Silverstalon Both $m$ and $n$ must be positive, so ...

Comment: @Silverstalon See my edit.

Comment: @saulspatz yes got it. I was wasting my time towards no of  pairs rather solution. the ans must be $0$ or $1$

Comment: @Silverstalon That's right.  If this answered your question, you should accept it by clicking the check mark, so that your question no longer shows as unsolved.